# Run animation again when this animation is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a simple Jquery animation I made below:

```
$('#message').animate({
    height: "+=50px"
}, 1000).delay(1000).animate({
    height: "-=50px"
}, 1000);
```

When I click on a button it does exactly that and it runs good.
When I click the button again while the animation is still running it adds it into a sort of queue and after the animation is done it runs another time.
So when I spam the button for 1 second long, it goes up and down, up and down and so on.

I have tried using .stop and.query functions but I can't make it work somehow.

I only want to run the animation when I click the button AND the animation is 'ready'.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with the queues, you can simply add a flag like `var animRunning = false;` and set it to true when you run the animation until it ends, then set it back to false. Of course, don't run the animation if the flag is already true.

Something like this:

```
if (animRunning)
    return false;
animRunning = true;
$('#message').animate({
    height: "+=50px"
}, 1000, function(){ // using the complete callback instead of delay here
    animate({
        height: "-=50px"
    }, 1000, function(){
        animRunning = false;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
 $('#message').stop(true,true).animate({
    height: "+=50px"
 }, 1000).delay(1000).animate({
    height: "-=50px"
 }, 1000);
```

Clears the animation queue and completes the current animation immediately every time you press the button.

Answer (score 0):

you said that you have tried .stop() and it doesnt work. question is, did you put it in the right place?

try:

```
$('#message').stop().animate({
height: "+=50px"
}, 1000).delay(1000).animate({
    height: "-=50px"
}, 1000);
```